# Map enum elements to types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to have a type per enum value but I don't quite know the syntax to map individual enum element to the type/interface.

Changing value of some parameters require a specific request body and some don't. ParameterOne and ParameterTwo do and ParameterThree doesn't.

```
enum Parameter {
  ParameterOne = 'ParameterOne',
  ParameterTwo = 'ParameterTwo',
  ParameterThree = 'ParameterThree',
}


interface UpdateParameterOneRequestBody {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface UpdateParameterTwoRequestBody {
  id: string;
  timestamp: number;
  price: number;
}
```

Final body will always include the following interface plus optionally a specific body from the above.

```
export interface UpdateParameterRequestBody<T extends Parameter> {
  parameter: T;
  value: boolean;
}
```

So it may result in `UpdateParameterTwoRequestBody & UpdateParameterRequestBody` etc. but will always contain the base `UpdateParameterRequestBody`.

I have tried creating a type and then using it extending the base but it seems I always need to include all the parameters for it to work and I don't want to do that.

```
type ParameterToRequest = {
  [Parameter.ParameterOne]: UpdateParameterOneRequestBody,
  [Parameter.ParameterTwo]: UpdateParameterTwoRequestBody,
};

type ParameterToRequestBody<T extends Parameter> = 
  UpdateParameterRequestBody<T> & T extends Parameter
    ? ParameterToRequestBodyTypes[T]
    : never;
```

> TS2536: Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'ParameterToRequestBodyTypes'.

[Here's a TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgJzhYAXYCoG8CwAoKWRZNDAeRGCgF4oByeJFdBC4OgGn0MZJYBUA7gHsa9XswxDhnbkSakE-ABYJgVWg2KSlq9bLwBffCbwBLECwBmcAMZUAqgAcAJnHQTFbAErAAjmDAAM6oAELCLgCe2HIgJABcUCEIFgDmANxycKnAieAQAEYYmUamFtZ2jq7uwJ4CIr4BwWER0bgEUGYuiclpJYSoZighyE55kEUI-VBOKfbjhcX4xnj4wAAeTsIIqJ2WGDb2UM5uHtqKjYEh4VEAPPxQG+ggLkHyfBgAfDEdTucsiX40wAbnAADaBRIFYTCMHAOAgEorfCoSJOKh1KTCS7NG6Rfho4JidqEADamIQADoKWwALqJE41GmUHHXVpcDrk-4YancpQienHapnBT1bH+K4tKIcwwlFGE946fjippsu4PJ6gV6KxTfWhyRkij4IVlSyL3b4AMigGvWz21FLkhAA-DqBCrJXiCeigqT+LSnVA8sBgcUgA)

Comment: `type P<T> = T extends keyof ParameterToRequestBodyTypes ? ParameterToRequestBodyTypes[T] : never;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this using `keyof`, note that you weren't too far off with what you had:

```js
type P<T extends Parameter> =
  T extends keyof ParameterToRequestBodyTypes
    ? UpdateParameterRequestBody<T> & ParameterToRequestBodyTypes[T]
    : UpdateParameterRequestBody<T>;

type A = P<'foobar'> // compile-time type error
type B = P<Parameter.ParameterOne> // uses UpdateParameterOneRequestBody 
type C = P<Parameter.ParameterTwo> // uses UpdateParameterTwoRequestBody
type D = P<Parameter.ParameterThree> // only UpdateParameterRequestBody
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=37&pln=34&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBACghgJzhYAXYCoG8CwAoKWRZNDAeRGCgF4oByeJFdBC4OgGn0MZJYBUA7gHsa9XswxDhnbkSakE-ABYJgVWg2KSlq9bLwBffCbwBLECwBmcAMZUAqgAcAJnHQTFbAErAAjmDAAM6oAELCLgCe2HIgJABcUCEIFgDmANxycKnAieAQAEYYmUamFtZ2jq7uwJ4CIr4BwWER0bgEUGYuiclpJYSoZighyE55kEUI-VBOKfbjhcX4xnj4wAAeTsIIqJ2WGDb2UM5uHtqKjYEh4VEAPPxQG+ggLkHyfBgAfDEdTucsiX40wAbnAADaBRIFYTCMHAOAgEorfCoSJOKh1KTCS7NG6Rfho4JidqEADamIQADoKWwALqJE41GmUHHXVpcDrk-4YancpQienHapnBT1bH+K4tKIcwwlFGE946fjippsu4PJ6gV6KxTfWhyRkij4IVlSyL3b4AMigGvWz21FLkhAA-DqBCrJXiCeigqT+LSnVA8sBgUtVnhUejYPdHnatW8KXq5Lb7W8ANbASLCKxurGmr2EoKB12G2p8-OtC1Qa0U5UVqLe4J+gMdQgM4Vl0UYevm-ifOURhUAQTEMFudCsMIKiDon3lUdCo9uFN5XdYlDng6jAGElyvayJN5GqAARPd81fGlRqYCboA)

Comment: Is there a way `&` union to be optional if not in `ParameterToRequest`. I don't want the never actually.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk yup. Updated answer and playground link.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```js
type ParameterToRequestBody<T extends Parameter & keyof ParameterToRequestBodyTypes> = 
  UpdateParameterRequestBody<T> & T extends Parameter
    ? ParameterToRequestBodyTypes[T]
    : never;
```

I added `& keyof ParameterToRequestBodyTypes` to the `T` constraint.